# Data from mongodb not displaying in view using EJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm using mongoose and express along with EJS. For some reason, data I have in my mongodb is not appearing in the view. I get no errors, it's just blank.

```
var Person = require('.././schema.js');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {

var peopleList = [];
var title = "Users in Database:";

Person.find(function (err, people) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    peopleList.push({name: people[i].name, role: people[i].role, wage: people[i].wage});
  }

  console.log(peopleList);
  console.log(peopleList[0].name + ' ' + peopleList[0].wage + ' ' + peopleList[0].role);
});

res.render('pages/about', {
  peopleList: peopleList,
  title: title
});
});
}
```

And in my view:

```
<h3><%= title %></h3>
<blockquote>
<ul>
<% for(var i = 0; i < peopleList.length; i++) { %>
  <li><%= peopleList[i].name %> : <%= peopleList[i].role %> : <%= peoplelist[i].wage %></li>
<% }; %>
</ul>
```

Alternate attempt:

```
<ul>
  <% peopleList.forEach(function(peopleList) { %>
      <li><%= peopleList.name %> - <%= peopleList.role %></li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

<%= title %> works just fine, just not the data. If I create my own array with objects in it and use the same forEach loop, it also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Person = require('.././schema.js');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {

var peopleList = [];
var title = "Users in Database:";

Person.find(function (err, people) {
  if (err) 
    return console.error(err);

  for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) 
  {
    peopleList.push({name: people[i].name, role: people[i].role, wage: people[i].wage});
  }

  console.log(peopleList);
  console.log(peopleList[0].name + ' ' + peopleList[0].wage + ' ' + peopleList[0].role);

  res.render('pages/about', {
  peopleList: peopleList,
  title: title
});

});

});
}
```

Please change your code to this.

Note: you should put `res.render` in the callback function of `Person.find`.